# BigQuery dynamic query to insert upon select SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

file.ini:-

---

> Blockquote

```
TAB1: table1
TAB2: table2
KEYS:
    col1: 'SKey'
NONKEYS:
    col2: 'SCode'
    col3: 'SName'
    col4: 'SState
```

file_data.csv:-

---

> Blockquote
>   SKey,SCode,SName,SState,EDate,CFlag
>   123,ABC,Acme Supply Co,CA,01/01/00,N
>   124,ABC,Acme Supply Co,IL,22/12/04,N
>   125,ABC,Acme Supply Co,CA,01/01/00,N
>   126,ABC,Acme Supply Co,IL,22/12/04,N
>   127,ABC,Acme Supply Co,CA,01/01/00,N
>   128,ABC,Acme Supply Co,IL,22/12/04,N
>   129,ABC,Acme Supply Co,CA,01/01/00,N
>   130,ABC,Acme Supply Co,IL,22/12/04,N
>   131,ABC,Acme Supply Co,CA,01/01/00,N
>   132,ABC,Acme Supply Co,IL,22/12/04,N

BQ Table :-

---

> Blockquote
>   SKey    SCode   SName   SEmail  SPhone  SState  EDate   Confirm 
>   123,ABC,Acme Supply Co,CA,01/01/00,N
>   The problem:

Two Step Job to perform.  Read file_data.csv file and insert to table2. The file.ini file would provide how many columns present in the file_data.csv and which are KEY or NONKEY. 
Form query such that compare SKey column in table1 and table2 and do insert to table1 where SKey column in table1=SKey column in table2 and rest of column data in table2 is different than in table1.

Only major catch is the number of columns to use in select query can vary based on the ini file ,KEYS and NONKEYS list items. The query has to be dynamic and accommodate KEYS and NONKEYS as many present in file.ini .
Every time new file.ini and file_data.csv has varying columns and corresponding KEYS and NONKEYS present..

The logic I am trying is:-
for each row in table2 compare each each col in table1 and 2 and wherever SKey matches (is same) and other data is not same (col3/4/5 etc) i.e different then insert those columns in table2 to table1 . But getting trouble to build all dynamic
query.

Comment: "But getting trouble to build all dynamic query." What have you tried so far? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am to post the python script which I developed for this purpose . But facing some issues